# Android: pass TextView data from ListView to TextView in another activity

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android ,how can I pass TextView data and image from ListView from main activity to set the data in the TextView in another activity to view it.
This code on ListView listener .

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MobileName",adapter.getItem(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And this is my adapter method,

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return emps.get(position);
}
```

This is activity I want to show data in,

```
id = findViewById(R.id.textOne1);
name = findViewById(R.id.textTwo2);
id.setText(getIntent());
name.setText();
```

*name* and *id* are TextView in another layout, I want to fill it from the data in *main activity*,
how can I get the data of each TextView from main activity to set *id* and *name* .

This is my adapter

```
public MyAdapter(List<Employee> emps,Context context){

    this.emps=emps;
    this.context=context;
    this.empFilters=emps;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return emps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return emps.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@ Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View myView=null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.for_list_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder();

        vh.idText=myView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        vh.nameText=myView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        vh.imageView=myView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        myView.setTag(vh);
    } else
       myView=convertView;


    Employee e=emps.get(position);
         ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)myView.getTag();

    vh.idText.setText(e.getId()+"");
    vh.nameText.setText(e.getName());
    vh.imageView.setImageResource(e.getImg());

    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter code where you get the data to show on textview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the extra(s) from the Intent using the appropriate method and the key used when putting the Extra.

e.g. `name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("MobileName"));` *(instead of `name.setText();`)*.

There's insufficient information regarding getting **id** so `id.setText(getIntent());` will do nothing of use:-

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it, depending on where you have declared your data object.
Say you have a List of data objects that you are displaying in a ListView. So your Activity class has:-

```
List<ListItemHolder> data = new ArrayList<>();
ListView lv;

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MobileId", data.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("MobileName", data.get(position).getName());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is your data pojo:-

```
class ListItemHolder{
    int id;
    String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now in the second activity, change the code to:-

```
id = findViewById(R.id.textOne1);
name = findViewById(R.id.textTwo2);
id.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("MobileId"));
name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("MobileName"));
```

I don't have access to Android Studio at the moment, so you might need to make some modifications to make it work.

Comment: thank you , when I write this asked me to put default value in this
id.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("MobileId"));
and when I put 0 
like this
id.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("MobileId",0));
the app stopped
where is the problem ?

Comment: "app stopped" doesn't mean anything. Check the logs, what's the error?